# Optimizations in security systems

Tags: security

I would like to know what we can mean by saying a optimized security system(physical or logical security system).

Does it mean something like a system which can monitor performance of services, SQL, DB maintenance, logs etc.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to give a little bit more detail to receive a serious answer.

Comment: Well what i am looking for is how can we bring optimization into access control, video surveillance systems in general security systems. Please let me know if it is still not clear. i would be glad to explain

Comment: Are you asking what the tipping point is between best optimization and best access control is?  Still not clear :(

Comment: no. What i am asking is suppose i have video surveillance application that i have developed, my question would be how do i improve so that the system is optimized in that it is stable, uses adequate resources and any other ways it can be optimized. 

I hope i am clear atleast now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimized is a general term, you will have to get specific in terms of defining what you need to consider it optimized to an "acceptable" level.  Plus there are different kinds of "optimization", such as for speed, memory usage, maintainability, etc.

Are you trying to figure out some criteria so that you can market your product as "optimized" and be able to explain it if someone asks what you mean?

If so, you need to figure out what your customers (or potential customers) actually care about.  If they care about video resolution and disk space usage (how much the system can store before having to archive elsewhere), then you need to make your application smart (optimized! :) in those areas.

THEN, you could be more specific in your marketing and say, "optimized to use XYZ resolution and store up to 2 weeks of video on a standard hardware setup!" - which would actually mean something tangible to your customers, and show them that you care about what they care about.